How do I execute a prepared statement using the Postgres-nio client?
I have created a simple prepared statement and want to execute that using posture-nio PostgresClient.
But this fails with the following error:

Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (PostgresNIO.PSQLError error 1.)

let rows = try await client.query("""
               EXECUTE prepared_statement(\(storeLevel.id)) ;
            """
             )
             
// Iterate the returned rows, decoding the rows into Swift primitives
for try await (id, tstamp) in rows.decode((String, Date).self) {
    let object = NewObj(id: id, tstamp: tstamp)
    objectBuf.append(object)
}


Not an answer, but it might be a solution: https://api.vapor.codes/postgresnio/documentation/postgresnio/postgrespreparedstatement

OK I figured it out.
Basically you have to use the PostgresPreparedStatement
struct PS_StoreLevelFixtures: PostgresPreparedStatement {
    static let sql = "SELECT id, tstamp, storelevelid, fixturenr, startdate, endDate FROM fixtures WHERE storelevelid=$1 order by fixturenr;"
    typealias Row = (String, Date, String, Int, Date, Date?)


    var storelevelid: String


    func makeBindings() -> PostgresBindings {
        var bindings = PostgresBindings()
        bindings.append(self.storelevelid)
        return bindings
    }


    func decodeRow(_ row: PostgresNIO.PostgresRow) throws -> Row {
        try row.decode(Row.self)
    }
}
struct PS_FixtureConfigurations: PostgresPreparedStatement {
    static let sql = "SELECT id, tstamp, fixtureid, startdate, enddate FROM fixtureConfigurations WHERE fixtureid=$1 order by startdate desc;"
    typealias Row = (String, Date, String,Date, Date?)


    var fixtureid: String


    func makeBindings() -> PostgresBindings {
        var bindings = PostgresBindings()
        bindings.append(self.fixtureid)
        return bindings
    }


    func decodeRow(_ row: PostgresNIO.PostgresRow) throws -> Row {
        try row.decode(Row.self)
    }
}

And then to execute something like the following:
 let fcs = PS_FixtureConfigurations(fixtureid: fixture.id)
 let configRows = try await client.execute(fcs)
                        
 // Iterate the returned rows, decoding the rows into Swift primitives
 for try await (id, tstamp, fixtureid, startdate, enddate) in configRows {
    let config = FixtureConfiguration(id: id, tstamp: tstamp, fixture: fixture, startDate: startdate, endDate: enddate)
    configBuf.append(config)
 }

